# How is a guild member's status determined and what does it mean?

Tags: animation-throwdown

So far, I've seen guild members be one of 3 statuses: active, slacking, and absent.  I have a general idea of what each means, but what criteria would cause a player to fall into each status?  Also, while the guild I'm in started off with lots of active players, pretty much all but 2 are now absent or slacking.  Do non-active members affect the guild or the bonuses it offer in any way?

[image: screenshot of statuses]

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering the same thing. I'm thinking that people who continue to play the game every day stay active, those that miss every other day are slacking but I'm not sure about absent. If I had to guess it's absent players have been away from the game for more than 48 hours, though I don't really know.  But I do know that it can affect the bonuses a guild receives. Absent players take away from the bonus gold percentage that you only get from active players.

Comment: I can confirm that absent players are the only status that will affect guild bonus.  Active and slacking both count towards the bonuses.